# how to write junit test case for this type of method?

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

Here is my method.

```
@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class XYZ {
    @GET
    @Path("/workflow")
    public Response getWorkflowsData() {    
        Object output=new Object();
        return Response.ok().entity(output).build();
        // or defination
    }
}
```

I am trying to do like this.

```
@Test
public void getWorkflowsDataTest() throws Exception{
     MvcResult result = mockMvc
            .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/workflow")).andReturn();
     String finalresult= result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
     assertEquals(200, result.getResponse().getStatus());
}
```

by this I am not able to go to the actual method.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `MockMvcRequestBuilders`, your test class should have `@SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` annotation, as well as `@ContextConfiguration` should be specified:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {YOUR_CONTEXT_CLASS_GOES_HERE.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyTestClass {

     @Resource
     private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

     private MockMvc mockMvc;

     @Before
     public void setup() {
         this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).build();
     }

     @Test
     public void getWorkflowsDataTest() throws Exception{
         MvcResult result = mockMvc
            .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/workflow")).andReturn();
         String finalresult= result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
         assertEquals(200, result.getResponse().getStatus());
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not able to call the actual method by using above code .